# A question of smooth local parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am confused about definition of local parametrization of John Lee’s books. The definition is following:
Suppose $S \subset M$ is an immersed $k-$dimensional submanifold. A local parametrization of $S$ is a continuous map $X: U \to M$ whose domain is an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, whose image is an open subset of S, and which, considered as a map into $S$, is a homeomorphism onto its image.

There are 3 possible topologies for $X(U)$, the subspace topology of M on S, the topology on M, and the topology on S. I read the answer of [Local Parametrizations of Immersed Submanifold - John Lee's Smooth Manifolds, p. 111](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186686/local-parametrizations-of-immersed-submanifold-john-lees-smooth-manifolds-p). However, I still have questions about it.

There is a proposition, which claims that if there is a smooth coordinate chart $(V, \varphi)$ for $S$ such that $X = \iota \circ \varphi^{-1}$, then it’s a smooth local parametrization.

If it’s subspace topology, $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $S$. Why $\iota \circ \varphi^{-1}(U)$ is open in subspace topology?

Moreover, if we consider $S$ equipped with subspace topology and coordinate maps $(X(U),X^{-1})$, why it’s not a smooth structure? What’s the gap between the real smooth structure on immersed submanifolds and the above one?

---

**Update:** Thanks for the comments. The topology we use here is the subspace topology. My following question is about the following proposition:

Suppose $M$ is aa smooth manifold, $S \subset M$ is an immersed $k$-submanifold, $\iota: S \to M$ is the inclusion map, and $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$. A map $U \to M$ is a smooth local parametrization of $S$ if and only if there is a smooth coordinate chart $(V,\varphi)$ for $S$ such that $X = \iota \circ \varphi^{-1}$.

My question is why the sufficient part is true. If I choose a chart $(V,\varphi)$, which is open in the immersed topology but not in the subspace topology, $X = \iota \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is not a local smooth parametrization, since the image is not open in the subspace topology.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the topology on $M$" or "the topology on $S$." There is either the subspace topology induced on $S$ by $M$ or the topology of $U$. As always, you should test out your thinking by considering the classical example of the immersed figure 8 in the plane.

Comment: It’s a good idea to start from that example. For the topology on M, I mean that $X(U)$ may contain elements not in S. (I think this should be a wrong possible choice.) The topology on S means that the induced topology such that S is immersed. (This could be different with the subspace topology.)

Comment: No, $X(U)\subset S$, so what you just said makes no sense. How is the "immersed topology" different from the subspace topology? To me, that's precisely the topology we speak of for an immersed submanifold. I do not know Jack Lee's book, but I can't believe he would go contrary to common usage.

Comment: In his book, if $F: M \to N$ is a smooth immersion, there is a topology defined by following: $U \subset F(M)$  is open if $F^{-1}(U)$ is open. This topology includes the subspace topology and is equal to the subspace topology if and only if $F$ is an embedding. It’s different because $F$ is not an open map.

Comment: OK, I misspoke, but you’re using letters now in different ways. I agree, of course, with the definition you just gave. The immersed topology comes from the topology on $M$ (but not the $M$ as you were originally using it). The second example of an immersed submanifold we should be thinking of is the  dense “line” on the torus. So the subspace topology from the torus disagrees with the topology on the real line (the topology of $S$ in your original).

Comment: It makes sense. My first confusion is that which topology we use when we define the smooth local parametrization. It seems that your answer is the subspace topology induced on $S$ by $M$. I agree with it. The following question is that there is a proposition: $S \subset M$ is an immersed submanifold. A map $X:U \to M$ is a smooth local parametrization of $S$ if and only if there is a smooth coordinate chart $(V,\varphi)$ for $S$, such that $X = \iota \circ \varphi^{-1}$, where $\iota$ is the inclusion.

Comment: If I choose a chart $(V, \varphi)$ on $S$, which is open in immersed topology, but not open in subspace topology, I think $X = \iota \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is not a local smooth parametrization, since $X(U) = \iota(V)$ is not open in the subspace topology.

Comment: The fact you have to deal with these ambiguities is another indication that one should avoid the notion of an immersed submanifold altogether and instead talk about immersions, as it is done for instance in the book by Guillemin and Pollack.